# Sudden Issue Running gulp build with a node_module - Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gulp, node-modules

I am getting a sudden issue when running a gulp build process for a web app that I can't work out how to fix.

The issue was NOT present on the evening of 25/01/2019, but when I try to run the gulp build process this morning (30/01/2019) I get an error returned and the build fails. Below is a copy of the error log (I have truncated some of the working directory paths for privacy):

```
../4551/node_modules/builtin-modules/index.js:2
const {builtinModules} = require('module');
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (../4551/node_modules/is-builtin-module/index.js:2:24)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (../4551/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js:4:23)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (../4551/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js:3:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (../4551/node_modules/read-pkg/index.js:4:28)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (../4551/node_modules/read-pkg-up/index.js:3:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at pkgUp (../4551/node_modules/gulp-environments/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:373:23)
at parseArgs (../4551/node_modules/gulp-environments/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:680:29)
at Object.Yargs.self.showHelp (../4551/node_modules/gulp-environments/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:502:23)
at Object.self.fail (../4551/node_modules/gulp-environments/node_modules/yargs/lib/usage.js:43:35)
at Function.Yargs.Object.defineProperty.get [as argv] (/home/rwd/phpci/PHPCI/build/4551/node_modules/gulp-environments/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:670:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (../4551/node_modules/gulp-environments/index.js:2:28)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (../4551/gulpfile.js:8:20)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:192:16)
at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/flagged-respawn/index.js:17:3)
at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:185:9)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:159:9
at /usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/v8flags/index.js:108:14
at /usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/v8flags/index.js:36:12
at /usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/v8flags/index.js:47:7
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:449:11)
at startup (node.js:146:18)
at node.js:404:3
```

While this error stems from a node_module, as far as I am aware this file hasn't changed in the past few days (last modified date of the file is 27/05/2019) so I have no idea why the build is suddenly failing.

As for the src code itself that I have changed since the last working build, I have only touched 1 line of code, changing a .includes() javascript function to a .indexOf() one for IE compatibility, nothing else has changed.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated as I am stumped otherwise...

Comment: Used `node` version has changed, maybe? (If you play with `nvm` for instance...) This code requires [at least version 6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: The node version being used is a fairly low one, version 5.10.0, but it has stayed this way for the past couple of years - no libraries have been added/amended at all between now and Friday when the build process was working. The web-app in general is due an upgrade, but until this is done we need the lower node version for some library compatibilities

Comment: Well, object destructuring started with Node v6, so go check the module that fails and force package.json to set an older version, because this module probably was updated with breaking changes the past few days... that or consider upgrading Node version! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stock Overflaw giving a couple of suggestions I have managed to resolve this myself. I tried upgrading my node version but this didn't work, so I checked the version of builtin-modules on the last working build versus the failing ones and it had updated from v1.1.1 to v3.0.0. I don't quite know why it had suddenly updated itself as nothing in its dependency tree had updated and v3.0.0 had been out for months already. Either way, forcing the build to use v.1.1.1 in my package.json appears to have fixed the problem.